Virtual column index not used in execution plan in Oracle database
I have created a virtual column from a text field to avoid content duplication, using the content hash value, as
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTENT (
    ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CONTENT VARCHAR(32767),
    CONTENT_HASH AS (STANDARD_HASH(CONTENT, 'SHA256')),
    METADATA VARCHAR(8192) CHECK (METADATA IS JSON)
);

I have used the STANDARD_HASH function from Oracle Database.
I have created an unique index on the virtual column as
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONTENT_HASH_IDX ON CONTENT (CONTENT_HASH);

I have considered the comments about Indexes on Extended Data Type Column
The index is working fine, avoiding to insert duplicated content.
But, when I try to use the index in a MERGE statement like
MERGE INTO CONTENT 
USING DUAL ON (CONTENT_HASH = :1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (CONTENT, METADATA)
 VALUES(:2, :3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET METADATA = :4

I check the plan, and see that is doing a FULL SCAN in CONTENT in every insertion.
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
MERGE INTO CONTENT 
USING DUAL ON (CONTENT_HASH = :1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CONTENT, METADATA)
    VALUES(:2, :3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET METADATA = :4;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);


'Plan hash value: 3741087930'
' '
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'| Id  | Operation                      | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |'
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                |                 |     1 |  2002 |  5541   (1)| 00:00:01 |'
'|   1 |  MERGE                         | CONTENT         |       |       |            |          |'
'|   2 |   VIEW                         |                 |       |       |            |          |'
'|   3 |    SEQUENCE                    | ISEQ$$_99907    |       |       |            |          |'
'|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER         |                 |     1 | 20528 |  5541   (1)| 00:00:01 |'
'|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | DUAL            |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |'
'|   6 |      VIEW                      | VW_LAT_A18161FF |     1 | 20526 |  5539   (1)| 00:00:01 |'
'|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| CONTENT         |     1 |  2035 |  5539   (1)| 00:00:01 |'
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' '
'Predicate Information (identified by operation id):'
'---------------------------------------------------'
' '
'   7 - filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */ "CONTENT" /*+ LOB_BY_VALUE */ ) AND '
'              RAWTOHEX("CONTENT_HASH")=:1 AND INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */ '
'              "CONTENT"."METADATA"))'
' '
'Note'
'-----'
'   - PDML disabled because object is not decorated with parallel clause'
'   - Direct Load disabled because no append hint given and not executing in parallel'
' '
'SQL Analysis Report (identified by operation id/Query Block Name/Object Alias):'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' '
'   7 -  SEL$2 / "CONTENT"@"SEL$2"'
'           -  The following columns have predicates which preclude their '
'              use as keys in index range scan. Consider rewriting the '
'              predicates.'
'                "CONTENT_HASH"'

Any suggestion will be really welcome

What data type are you binding for :1, the content_hash?  Your explain plan seems to show that Oracle needs to make a RAWTOHEX call on content_hash which (as the SQL Analysis Report calls out) means that the index can't be used.

7 - filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /*+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD / "CONTENT" /+
LOB_BY_VALUE / ) AND RAWTOHEX("CONTENT_HASH")=:1 AND
INTERNAL_FUNCTION( /+ LVC_LAZY_LOAD */
"CONTENT"."METADATA"))'

which makes me suspect you are passing a varchar2 string to the query not a raw.  If you can pass in a raw, that is one option.  Another would be to have your computed column be the hex string of the hash rather than the raw hash itself.

Thank you. You are right and I have changed the calling code (in python) to use bytes for mapping the raw. But this open other question. When I asked for the plan in SQL*Plus, with EXPLAIN PLAN, it does not know the calling code. So it was recovering the plan from cache?

You can try:
MERGE INTO CONTENT dst
USING (SELECT :1 AS content, :2 AS metadata FROM DUAL) src
ON (dst.CONTENT_HASH = STANDARD_HASH(src.content, 'SHA256'))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (CONTENT, METADATA)
  VALUES(src.content, src.metadata)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET METADATA = src.metadata

Which gives the explain plan:
Plan hash value: 4090019035
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                 |                  |     1 |  4053 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE                          | CONTENT          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                          |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    SEQUENCE                     | ISEQ$$_500078    |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                  |     1 |  4083 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      VIEW                       |                  |     1 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       FAST DUAL                 |                  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONTENT          |     1 |  4047 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | CONTENT_HASH_IDX |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   8 - access("DST"."CONTENT_HASH"(+)=STANDARD_HASH("SRC"."CONTENT",'SHA256'))
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)


If you want to use your query and are passing in the SHA-256 hash as a hexadecimal string then you can wrap the bind variable in UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW:
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
MERGE INTO CONTENT 
USING DUAL
ON (CONTENT_HASH = UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(:1))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CONTENT, METADATA)
    VALUES(:2, :3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET METADATA = :4;

fiddle

Thank you very much!!! I have changed both, the calling code to use binary and the syntax, and now is working (from 50000 seconds to 500 the full code!!!)

Finally I got this working:

I have changed the python call to avoid the HEX-to-RAW conversions
I have reformatted the MERGE to avoid the use of DUAL (using new syntax in 23ai)

This is my code:
import hashlib
import json

# Oracle database
# %pip install oracledb
import oracledb
from oracledb import Connection

def save_chunks(connection: Connection, rows: list[tuple[str, dict]]) -> None:
    prepared_data = []
    for row in rows:
        prepared_data.append((
            # hashlib.sha256(row[0].encode("utf-8")).hexdigest().upper(), # Hash
            row[0], # Content 
            json.dumps(row[1]), # Metadata
            hashlib.sha256(row[0].encode("utf-8")).digest(), # Hash
        ))
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        try:
            # Doc: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html
            content_id_var = cursor.var(int, arraysize=len(prepared_data))
            cursor.setinputsizes(None, None, None, content_id_var)
            cursor.executemany(f"""
                                MERGE INTO CONTENT 
                                USING (VALUES(:1, :2)) AS C(CONTENT, METADATA) ON (CONTENT_HASH = :3)
                                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                                    INSERT (CONTENT, METADATA)
                                    VALUES(C.CONTENT, C.METADATA)
                                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                    UPDATE SET METADATA = C.METADATA
                                RETURNING ID INTO :4
                               """,
                            prepared_data,
                            batcherrors=True)
            
            
            for error in cursor.getbatcherrors():
                logging.error(f"Error inserting content: {error.message} at row offset {error.offset}")
            for i, data in enumerate(rows):
                logging.debug(f"MERGED CONTENT.ID={content_id_var.getvalue(i)} ")

P.S: Thank you, Justin Cave and MT0 for your useful answers.
